# List and delete all Enterprise Apps installed in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios4

I am trying to develop an application which lists a set of enterprise application along with the installation status.I tried to do his by accessing "com.apple.mobile.installation.plist",but i am not aware about its exact location in device.Also this is an enterprise application so device should provide access to get this information some way..Looking for a solution.Also i need to delete the apps also ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cannot be done. App installation and deletion requires user initiative.